# How to get results from multiple queries at once with pg-promise?

Tags: javascript, pg-promise

Currently I have the following code to get the results of two queries

```
dbro.many("SELECT geoname_id, country_name FROM paises WHERE locale_code=$1 LIMIT 10",data.lang)
   .then(function(countriesData){
      data.countries=countriesData;
      dbro.many("SELECT * FROM categorias")
       .then(function(categoriesData){
         data.categories=(categoriesData)
         console.log(data);
         res.render('layout', data);
         res.end();
      })
       .catch(function(err){
        console.log("error while fetching categories data");
      })
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log("error while fetching countries data",err);
    });
```

Somehow I think this is not right. What if I need to get the results of many queries before returning the callback? The nesting of several then/catch becomes hideous. The objective is to have all the data ready before rendering a page (in Express)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) documentation has [plenty of examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example) of how to execute multiple queries.

**Initialization**

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(/* initialization options */);
const db = pgp('postgres://username:password@host:port/database');
```

When queries depend on each other we **should** use a task:

```
db.task('get-user-events', async t => {
        const user = await t.one('select * from users where id = $1', 123);
        return t.any('select * from events where login = $1', user.name);
})
    .then(data => {
        // data = result from the last query;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error
    });
```

When queries have no dependencies between them:

```
db.task('get-everything', async t => {
    const users = await t.any('select * from users');
    const count = await t.one('select count(*) from events', [], a => +a.count);
    return {users, count};
})
    .then({users, count} => {

    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error
    });
```

And when the queries change the data, we **should** replace [task](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#tasks) with [tx](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#transactions) for transaction.

Note that I emphasized each statement with **"should"**, as you can execute everything outside of tasks or transactions, but it is not recommended, due to the way database connections are managed.

You **should** only execute queries on the root protocol (`db` object) when you need to execute a single query per HTTP request. Multiple queries at once **should** always be executed within tasks/transactions.

See also [Chaining Queries](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/chaining-queries), with its main point at the bottom there:

> If you do not follow the advised approach, your application will perform better under a small load, due to more connections allocated in parallel, but under a heavy load it will quickly deplete the connection pool, crippling performance and scalability of your application.

**UPDATE**

Starting from [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) v7.0.0 we can pull results from multiple independent queries in a single command, which is much more efficient than all of the previous solutions:

```js
const {users, count} = await db.multi('SELECT * FROM users;SELECT count(*) FROM events');
```

The library implements [helpers.concat](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.concat), to format and concatenate multiple queries.

See also methods: [multi](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi) and [multiResult](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multiResult).

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. I did read the documentation but I missed the crucial part (at least for me):

 // data[0] = result from the first query;
        // data[1] = result from the second query;

(result data as an array)

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks for your examples. However, how would you go if you had to mix both ? In my task I run 5 independent queries. Each one return the latest insert id. Once this task is done, I need to run a last query, which would use all the ids produces by the task. I haven't managed to mix both so far. Do you have any idea. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Stanislasdrg what you are asking is more about basic use of promises rather than this library. You do `return t.batch([...your 5 inserts...]).then(data=>t.query(...query based on data...))`.

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks for your example. How will you do a more complicated chain? for example "get all users named john" and then "get their children's name" and return as `[{ firstname:"John", lastname:"dep", children:[{name:...},{...}] } ,{ ... ]`

Comment: @Parham are you talking about a simple one-to-many request? Anyhow, this message board is a poor place for such discussion. Ask a separate question on StackOverflow, I will answer it ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t Many to Many is more of what I have in mind. I just posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586486/best-way-to-query-a-many-to-many-relationship-using-pg-promise . Thanks

Comment: @DavidNoriega The answer has received an update for the latest version of the library.

Comment: @vitaly-t When/why would one use batch instead of multi if the latter is better?

Comment: @Code Actually, it is neither. In practice, you would need to format queries a lot, and so if they do not have dependency, then you can use [helpers.concat](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.concat), and only then [multi](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi). Other than that, approach with [multi](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi) is simply newer. Method `batch` allows for some dependency, as it can execute functions that return queries.

Comment: I see @vitaly-t answer, I upvote :) curious question, if there is an error in await t.one wont it trigger an unhandledpromiserejection?

Comment: @PirateApp No, it will be handled by `catch` on the task.