# Node.js - How to chain Promise in The right way

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, promise

I recently moved from *callback* functions to *promises* in node.js. I want to preform async query to the DB (psql) in the most elegant way. I was wondering if the following code is the right way to do it or if I can chain for example the promises in a way of `first().then(second).then(third)`.

```
function queryAll(req, res) {
    searchQuery()
    .then((rows) => {
        console.log(rows);
        totalQuery()
        .then((total) => {
            console.log(total);
        });
    });
    res.json({"rows": rows, "total": total});
}

function searchQuery() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var rowData = { rows: {} };
        pool.query('select age, sex from workers;', values, function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                return console.error('error running query', err);
                reject(err);
            }
            rowData.rows = result.rows;
            resolve(rowData);
        });
    });
}

function totalQuery() {
    return new Promise(function(reject, resolve) {
        var totalData = { totals: {} };
        pool.query('select sex, scores from workers group by sex;', values, function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                return console.error('error running query', err);
                reject(err);
            }
            totalData.totals = result.rows;
            resolve(totalData);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var rowData = { rows: {} };
var totalData = { totals: {} };
```

First of all, these make no sense stored in variables since there's nothing else on the object. Just resolve with the rows directly instead.

```
return console.error('error running query', err);
```

Also, don't just `console.log` your errors. `then` accepts a second callback that executes on thrown errors or rejected promises. Throw this message in an error or reject with it instead. Also, I would leave logging to the consumer.

```
function queryAll(req, res) {
    searchQuery()
    .then((search) => {
        console.log(rows);
        totalQuery()
        .then((total) => {
            console.log(total);
        });
    });
    res.json({"rows": rows, "total": total});
}
```

`rows` and `total` don't exist anywhere. Plus, by the time `res.json` executes, `rows` and `total` (assuming they come from inside the callbacks) won't exist yet since the whole sequence is async. You'll get undefined values as results.

I see little point in running `searchQuery` and `totalQuery` in sequence as they're not dependent on each other. It's better to run them parallel instead. Use `Promise.all` for that.

```
function queryAll(req, res) {
  Promise.all([
    searchQuery(),
    totalQuery()
  ]).then(values => {
    const rows = values[0];
    const total = values[1];
    res.json({"rows": rows, "total": total});
  }, function(e){
    // something went wrong
  });
}

function searchQuery() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    pool.query('select age, sex from workers;', values, function(err, result) {
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve(result.rows);
    });
  });
}

function totalQuery() {
  return new Promise(function(reject, resolve) {
    pool.query('select sex, scores from workers group by sex;', values, function(err, result) {
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve(result.rows);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a few issues in the code:

- You `return` before executing `reject()`
- There is an undefined `rows` variable (mismatch with `search`)
- `res.json` is executed before the results are in.
- The promises resolve to objects like `{ rows: rows }`, but the main function seems to expect the plain numbers, not the objects. So let the promises just resolve to numeric values.
- The second SQL is ambiguous since the second field is not aggregated and does not appear in the `group by` clause either. Assuming you want to sum the scores, use `sum()`.
- The second query is only launched after the first one has returned results, but this can be done in parallel
- You have very similar code repeated. Try to reuse code and make the SQL statement an argument.

Here is how I would suggest to do it:

```
function queryAll(req, res) {
    return Promise.all([searchQuery(), totalQuery()]).then(([rows, total]) => {
        console.log('rows', rows);
        console.log('total', total);
        // Make sure to only access the promised values in the `then` callback
        res.json({rows, total});
    });
}

function searchQuery() {
    return promiseQuery('select age, sex from workers;');
}

function totalQuery() {
    // When you group, make sure to aggregate:
    return promiseQuery('select sex, sum(scores) as scores from workers group by sex;');
}

function promiseQuery(sql) { // reusable for other SQL queries
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        pool.query(sql, values, function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                // Do not return before calling reject!
                console.error('error running query', err);
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            // No need for a variable or object, just resolve with the number of rows
            resolve(result.rows);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I fixed the rows variable.

Comment: That is OK, but don't apply all the fixes that are provided to you in the answers, or you will not have a question anymore. Just leave the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant solution would be via [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
function queryAll(req, res) {
    db.task(t => {
        return t.batch([
            t.any('SELECT age, sex FROM workers', values),
            t.any('SELECT sex, scores FROM workers GROUP BY sex', values)
        ]);
    })
        .then(data => {
            res.json({rows: data[0], total: data[1]});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // handle error
        });
}
```

And that's everything. You don't have to reinvent promise patterns for working with the database, they are all part of the library already.

And if your queries have a dependency, see: [How to get results from multiple queries at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737613/how-to-get-results-from-multiple-queries-at-once-with-pg-promise).

Or if you prefer ES6 generators:

```
function queryAll(req, res) {
    db.task(function* (t) {
        let rows = yield t.any('SELECT age, sex FROM workers', values);
        let total = yield t.any('SELECT sex, scores FROM workers GROUP BY sex', values);
        return {rows, total};
    })
        .then(data => {
            res.json(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // handle error
        });
}
```

And with the ES7's `await/async` it would be almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are some errors in your code, you have to place the `reject` before the return, otherwise it will be never called, and create a dangling promise:

```
function searchQuery() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var rowData = {
      rows: {}
    };

    pool.query('select age, sex from workers;', values, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        console.error('error running query', err);
      } else {
        rowData.rows = result.rows;
        resolve(rowData);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Beside that you should not nest the Promises when ever possible.

So it should be:

```
 function queryAll(req, res) {
   var result = {}; 
   searchQuery()
     .then((search) => {
       console.log(search);
       result.rows = search;
       return totalQuery();
     })
     .then((total) => {
       result.total = total;
       console.log(total);
     });
 }
```

The `res.json` has to be called in the `then` part of the Promise:

```
 function queryAll(req, res) {
   var result = {}; 
   searchQuery()
     .then((search) => {
       console.log(search);
       result.rows = search;
       return totalQuery();
     })
     .then((total) => {
       result.total = total;
       console.log(total);
     })
     .then(() => {
       res.json({
         "rows": result.rows,
         "total": result.total
       });
     });
 }
```

If your `queryAll` is called as e.g. middleware of express, then you should handle the `catch` case within `queryAll`:

```
 function queryAll(req, res) {
   var result = {}; 
   searchQuery()
     .then((search) => {
       console.log(search);
       result.rows = search;
       return totalQuery();
     })
     .then((total) => {
       result.total = total;
       console.log(total);
     })
     .then(() => {
       res.json({
         "rows": result.rows,
         "total": result.total
       });
     })
     .catch( err => {
        res.status(500).json({error: 'some error'})
     });
 }
```

For postgress I would suggest to use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) instead of using a callback style library and wrapping it into promises yourself.

You could simplify the code if you use a library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/):

```
 const bPromise = require('bluebird')

 function queryAll(req, res) {
   bPromise.all([
     searchQuery(),
     totalQuery()
   ])
   .spread((rows, total) => {
       res.json({
         "rows": rows,
         "total": total
       });
     })
     .catch(err => {
       res.status(500).json({
         error: 'some error'
       })
     });
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

With [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs) your logic may be coded as simple as this:

```
var resp = {
    rows: dbQuery(nsynjsCtx, conn, 'select age, sex from workers', values1).data,
    total: dbQuery(nsynjsCtx, conn, 'select sex, scores from workers group by sex', values2).data
};
```

Please see example of multiple sequential queries here: https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/tree/master/examples/node-mysql